# How to decode a JSON with same variables in two different keys?

Tags: swift, decodable

I am learning `Decodables`. Here is my model:

```
struct DQModel: Decodable{  
    var details: DQDetails
}

struct DQDetails: Decodable {   
    var weekly_details: WeeklyDetails   
    var your_turn: MyTurn   
    var their_turn: TheirTurn    
}

struct  WeeklyDetails: Decodable {  
    var win: Int?   
    var loss: Int?
}

struct MyTurn: Decodable {
    var name: String?   
    var pic: String?    
    var current: String?    
    var time: String?   
    var win: Int?   
    var loss: Int?    
}

struct TheirTurn: Decodable {   
    var name: String?   
    var pic: String?    
    var current: String?    
    var time: String?   
    var win: Int?   
    var loss: Int?
}
```

You can see here that `MyTurn` and `TheirTurn` are exactly the same with the same variables, but they are just different keys. Is there any way that I do not have to rewrite the `variables` again? Or in future, if any case arrives like out of 10, 9 are same, is there any approach which I can follow to reduce copy/paste work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As *you are learning* please avoid *snake_cased* variables by specifying `.convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy and don't declare all struct members schematically as optional. Declare only those struct members as optional whose keys can be missing.

Comment: Ok so you are saying that if I use `weekly_details.convertFromSnakeCase`, then I will be able to use it as `weeklyDetails`? Can you show me how to use one? Not getting it.

Comment: If the key is `your_turn` declare the struct member as `yourTurn` and add the key decoding strategy to the decoder :`let decoder = JSONDecoder(); decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase`. The strategy affects all *snaked_cased* keys

Comment: @vadian Great Tip! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a common 'struct' for turn and use them in both the cases(myTurn & theirTurn). You can do this as below:

```
struct Turn: Decodable {

var name: String?

var pic: String?

var current: String?

var time: String?

var win: Int?

var loss: Int?
}
```

and use this like:

```
struct DQDetails: Decodable {

var weekly_details: WeeklyDetails

var your_turn: Turn

var their_turn: Turn

}
```

It will reduce your effort in creating two different structures.

Comment: Hey, I thought about the same thing, but suppose in any other struct there are 9/10 variables same, then what should I do?

Comment: @Rob13: In such case, you can make that one extra variable 'optional' OR you can use default value for that extra variable. By doing this, you'll be able to use your struct in both the cases with different number of variable along with common ones.